# What Visual Studio 2017 option is required to create an F# ASP.NET Core Web Application?

Tags: asp.net, f#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have created an F# ASP.NET project in .Net Core by using `dotnet new mvc --lang F#`.

That works fine but in that setting I don't get built in integration with IIS Express. I have switched over to Visual Studio 2017 because IIS Express debugging is built in and when I try to create a new project the ASP.NET Core Web Application template only shows up under C#. I have installed the F# language support option for Visual Studio 2017 but that did not help. The F# templates do not include ASP.NET Core Web Application.

Is there another option that will enable the creation of ASP.NET Core Web Application with F# in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: It's probably just missing templates (I know the VS team are working on the templating story right now). Is there a reason you can't use `dotnet new...`?

Comment: @DavidG Maybe I can. I would like to use Visual Studio 2017 because the launchSettings.json and IIS Express integration are pretty smooth. I'll try to dotnet new the project and then load it in Visual Studio 2017. I'll have to cobble this together with a lauchSettings.json and get everything working. I was just hoping to avoid the fuss.

Comment: You can create the project with `dotnet new` and still use Visual Studio with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Visual Studio 2017 doesn't yet support F# .NET Core apps.  Last I heard, this was targeted for version 15.3, which is still in preview, but I haven't tried out the preview version yet.

> The Visual F# Tools project system does not support F# on .NET Core
>
> - The new .fsproj file does not load in VS
> - No project system support for package load, cross-platform build, or publish
> - No .NET Core templates in-box
> - This means you can create something with the .NET CLI and have it fail to load in Visual Studio

https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/2400

Comment: +1 for a nice conclusive answers. I'll stick with dotnet new and VS Code for this project. I've seen some leads on wiring up IIS Express with the VS Code debugging. I think everything I need is there I'll have learn how to use the launch.json features.

Comment: Apparently the latest update is that it doesn't work in VS 15.3 either.
"Unfortunately, we’re not quite happy enough with the quality in the 15.3 update to announce that it’s fully supported."
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/f-and-net-core-roadmap-update/#Visual-Studio-tooling-support

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are a number of dotnetcore templates available for F# developers to start with. You can generate the templates and use them in visual studio in the same way you would any other projects\solutions.

I've had a couple issues with a few on my mac but, they seem to work well enough on windows.
https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Available-templates-for-dotnet-new

Comment: OP is asking about VS templates, not `dotnet new...`

Comment: "Is there another option that will enable the creation of ASP.NET Core Web Application in F#?" He is asking for another option. He doesn't specify that the option is necessarily with VS2017, only that he tried to use VS2017.

Comment: Look at the question title though. And the body of the question already states they can create with the CLI. The confusion seems to be that he thinks the two are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Terrance Those templates are a helpful resource. If my attempts with Visual Studio 2017 fail I'll try them next.